# Full screen mode game view in editor

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-development

I am trying to make my game view full screen and I have found few scripts online in order to achieve this. Unfortunately I am not able to execute them in 2020 version (or 2018+). Is there a method to enable full screen game window during editor mode?
From the below script, I get exception error at `System.Object Res = GetMainGameView.Invoke (null, null);` Is the current Unity version not accessible for the GetMainGameView?

```
using UnityEditor;
using UnityEngine;

namespace FullScreenPlayModes {
    [InitializeOnLoad]
    public class FullScreenPlayMode : Editor {
        //The size of the toolbar above the game view, excluding the OS border.
        private static int toolbarHeight = 22;

        static FullScreenPlayMode () {
            EditorApplication.playModeStateChanged -= PlayModeStateChanged;
            EditorApplication.playModeStateChanged += PlayModeStateChanged;
        }

        static void PlayModeStateChanged (PlayModeStateChange _playModeStateChange) {
            if (PlayerPrefs.GetInt ("PlayMode_FullScreen", 0) == 1) {
                // Get game editor window
                EditorApplication.ExecuteMenuItem ("Window/General/Game");
                System.Type T = System.Type.GetType ("UnityEditor.GameView,UnityEditor");
                System.Reflection.MethodInfo GetMainGameView = T.GetMethod ("GetMainGameView", System.Reflection.BindingFlags.NonPublic | System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Static);
                System.Object Res = GetMainGameView.Invoke (null, null);
                EditorWindow gameView = (EditorWindow) Res;

                switch (_playModeStateChange) {
                    case PlayModeStateChange.EnteredPlayMode:

                        Rect newPos = new Rect (0, 0 - toolbarHeight, Screen.currentResolution.width, Screen.currentResolution.height + toolbarHeight);

                        gameView.position = newPos;
                        gameView.minSize = new Vector2 (Screen.currentResolution.width, Screen.currentResolution.height + toolbarHeight);
                        gameView.maxSize = gameView.minSize;
                        gameView.position = newPos;

                        break;

                    case PlayModeStateChange.EnteredEditMode:

                        gameView.Close ();

                        break;
                }
            }
        }

        [MenuItem ("Tools/Editor/Play Mode/Full Screen", false, 0)]
        public static void PlayModeFullScreen () {
            PlayerPrefs.SetInt ("PlayMode_FullScreen", 1);
        }

        [MenuItem ("Tools/Editor/Play Mode/Full Screen", true, 0)]
        public static bool PlayModeFullScreenValidate () {
            return PlayerPrefs.GetInt ("PlayMode_FullScreen", 0) == 0;
        }

        [MenuItem ("Tools/Editor/Play Mode/Window", false, 0)]
        public static void PlayModeWindow () {
            PlayerPrefs.SetInt ("PlayMode_FullScreen", 0);
        }

        [MenuItem ("Tools/Editor/Play Mode/Window", true, 0)]
        public static bool PlayModeWindowValidate () {
            return PlayerPrefs.GetInt ("PlayMode_FullScreen", 0) == 1;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Is this for the same reason as the last time "Just because" ? ... Because you know .. there is a built-in button for this in the UI so why not use it? ^^ And btw you know there is [`WindowLayout.Mximize`](https://github.com/Unity-Technologies/UnityCsReference/blob/61f92bd79ae862c4465d35270f9d1d57befd1761/Editor/Mono/GUI/WindowLayout.cs#L871) you could probably use ;)

Comment: Hey @derHugo Thanks for your comment. I did not know if there is a built-in button for this. Could you please elaborate how to activate it? My motive is to hide the Game view tab in editor mode.

Comment: If you undock the Game tab into its own maximised window, you'll get *close* to fullscreen.

Comment: @Immersive yes ofc i know that. But I need a complete full screen without the tab view.

Answer (score 0):

I know this was asked a year ago but maybe this will be useful to someone.

If you can afford it, I recommend this asset called Fullscreen Editor.
https://assetstore.unity.com/packages/tools/utilities/fullscreen-editor-69534

Alternatively, unity has a built-in package in the package manager with an editor recorder. This will automatically record your gameplay with none of the editor UI or your app bar in the way.

Or as someone else stated, make a test build or use the "maximize on play button" in the editor panel.

Answer (score 0):

Do the following steps to play video in full screen mode.

- Drop your video clip into the Assets folder.
- Create an empty game object in your scene and add the video player component to it.

[image] [image]

- Add your video clip to the empty Video Clip in the component. You can next check the settings and add Loop if you want.
- **Set the video player Render Mode as Near Plane (Important).**
- **Assign Main Camera to the Camera attribute in the video player (Important)**
  [image]
- Done.

Answer (score -2):

Most people would suggest use "maximize on play button" which is not you want.

I would suggest if you want to test the look of your game in full screen just build and run after you edit Build settings/Player settings  and make the game there full screen or even let use to use alt+enter to go full screen and test your look.

This will be much easier than using in game scripts just to test full screen in editor UNLESS you want to see console output while in full screen. There is also a free asset in store  see the console in build.

https://assetstore.unity.com/packages/tools/gui/in-game-debug-console-68068

Comment: There are plenty of reasons to want actual full screen in editor, such as doing captures.